# Cassandra Consistency (when nodes offline)

Tags: java, cassandra, consistency

Lets assume I have a cluster of 4 nodes.

And I initiate a write operation with `ConsistenyLevel.ALL`

Assuming all 4 nodes are connected, it would succeed as expected.

Assuming all 4 nodes are connected, but 1 fails for whatever reason (primary key already exists, etc). it would fail.

My question is:

if 1 of the 4 nodes is offline, when executing a write with `ConsistentyLevel.ALL` will it fail?
or does it consider 'reachability'? (i.e. if the node is offline..the effective cluster size is 3 and not 4).

If it were to succeed, when the 4 node comes back online does it sync before accepting new client requests?

ps. not sure if this matters but I would be using the Datastax Java Driver.

Answer (score 1):

A request will fail if you specify Consistency level ALL and any of the replicas known to the cluster that are responsible for that query are not up. Once a node has completed joining the cluster and has been assigned a token range it is always considered for CL guarantees and replication. It only is removed from those responsibilities when `nodetool decommission` is run removing it from the cluster.

Lets say you have a 4 node cluster with Replication Factor = 2. This means regardless of how many nodes are up or down all the members of the cluster know there should be 2 copies of every piece of data. If you then perform a query when 2 nodes are down and you have a Consistency level of ALL, that query will fail if either of those nodes was responsible for a replica of the information you were trying to write or read.

---

### Example

Given a 4 node cluster with responsibilities as follows

```
Node 1 { A, D }
Node 2 { B, A }
Node 3 { C, B }
Node 4 { D, C }
```

#### Nodes 3 & 4 are down

Given Consistency Level All

```
Select * where partition key hashes to range A
```

This will pass since Node 1 and 2 are the only nodes responsible for A data and they are
 both up

```
Select * where partition key hashes to range B
```

This will fail since only 1 of 2 known nodes which are responsible for B are up (Node 2 up but Node 3 is Down)

Comment: RussS I would change first sentence "A request will fail if you specify Consistency level ALL and any of the replicas known to the cluster that are responsible for that query is not up"

Answer (score 1):

The number of nodes isn't the determining factor. The replication factor plays a bigger role. Even then, it's not straightforward:

Let's assume replication factor is 3, and you've specified Quorum (or ALL...). The node handling the request is the coordinator for the request. Let's assume the request is a write.

- If the coordinator knows that nodes are down so as to fail requests consistency level, the request "fails". The coordinator will "know" about nodes being down through gossip.
- If the coordinator knows that sufficient nodes are up, then it'll issue the write to all replicas. It will wait for responses from the required number of nodes as per consistency level. If it receives sufficient acks, the request succeeds. However, if it doesn't receive sufficient acks within the timeout, then the request "times out" (not a "fail"). This means that nodes coming back up will either "complete" the write via hinted handoff, or on the next query. This might seem "weird", but have a read of this:
  http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-cassandra-deals-with-replica-failure
  and in a bit more detail, this:
  http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201102.mbox/%3CAANLkTimEGp8H87mGs_BxZKNCk-A59whXF-Xx58HcAWZm@mail.gmail.com%3E

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> if 1 of the 4 nodes is offline, when executing a write with ConsistentyLevel.ALL will it fail?
>   or does it consider 'reachability'? (i.e. if the node is offline..the effective cluster size is 3 and not 4).

yes it will fail.  Cassandra has tunable consistency, but your trading partition tolerance.  When using CL.ALL you cannot handle any node failure.  You should use CL.ONE wherever you can and use CL.QUORUM for both read/writes when you need data to be consistent but still want to be able to handle some node failure (assuming replication factor >=3 which you should be running).  There is very rare scenarios where ALL should be used.